Firefox Add-on auto update for self-hosted on intranet
I have a self-hosted add-on that I'd like to use the auto-update feature for all users on my internal network. I have an update file located with my version files and my manifest has an update_url pointing to it. I'm using vscode and the files are hosted on Jira Confluence.
I'll type samples here since it's not on this machine/network.
In manifest.json:
"browser_specific_settings: {
    "gecko": {
        "id": <my id>,
        "update_url": https://<my_update_url>
    }
}

In update.json:
{
    "addons":{
        <my id>:{
            "updates": [
            {
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "update_link": https://<link to file>
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}

The browser console shows numerous errors when I click "check for updates" under "Manage Your Extensions". Since I can't copy/paste them in here, I'll do my best to provide some info:
addons.update-checker WARN onUpdateCheckComplete failed to parse update manifest: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

After that, there are numerous errors from Toolkit.Telemetry trying to connect to mozilla, which it can't, because it's not connected to the internet.
There's no mention in the console of the URLs for the update.json or the add on files themselves.
My extension is unsigned, and as far as I know getting it signed is not an option. I've tried searching the Firefox extension pages, but not much there for unsigned addons, and so far in SO none of the problems others have faced are similar enough to mine.
